# Laravel Guzzle parameters

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle6, guzzle

From the API docs I have this `curl` request:

```
curl https://api.example.com/api/Jwt/Token ^
        -d Username="asd%40gmail.com" ^
        -d Password="abcd1234"
```

Now I'm trying to create that request in Laravel 5.1 using the Guzzle library so I wrote:

```
 public function test()
    {

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$res = $client->createRequest('POST','https://api.example.com/api/Jwt/Token', [

    'form_params' => [
        'Username' => 'asd%40gmail.com',
        'Password' => 'abcd1234'
]
            ]);

$res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);

dd ($res);
}
```

But I get this error:

```
***ErrorException in Client.php line 126:
Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array,     string given, called in     /home/ibook/public_html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 87 and defined***
```

WHat is the problem and how do I solve that error?

p.s. I also tried

```
$res = $client->createRequest('POST','https://api.example.com/api/Jwt/Token', 

    'form_params' => [
        'Username' => 'asd%40gmail.com',
        'Password' => 'abcd1234'

            ]);
```

But then I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are calling the `createRequest` function instead of `request`. This should work:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.example.com/api/Jwt/Token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'Username' => 'asd%40gmail.com',
        'Password' => 'abcd1234'
    ]
]);
```

Check the [documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#post-form-requests)